# How is the formula for expressing a cyclotomic polynomial derived.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, field-theory

$\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+.....+x+1=f(x)$ a cyclotomic polynomial.

But I cant seem to work out how this equality is found.

I Tried expressing it as a geometric series

$$\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=\frac{x^p-1}{x(1-\frac{1}{x})}=\frac{x^p-1}{x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{x^p-1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^p\frac{1}{x^n}$$

But this didn't produce the correct equation , does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: Just multiply $x^{p-1}+...+x+1$ by $x-1$. Note that you obtain
$x^p+x^{p-1}+...+x-(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+1) = x^p-1$.

Comment: Presumably $p$ is supposed to be a prime number here. Otherwise, the polynomial you defined as $f(x)$ would not be a cyclotomic polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** 
Calculate
$$(x-1)(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+x+1)$$
by doing the multiplication.

Comment: ah you obtain $x^p-1$ :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your terminology. But $$x^{n+1}-1=(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)$$ for any $n\in\Bbb{N}.$ For example $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ and $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and so on.
One way to give a rigorous proof is for this identity is induction and there are so many other ways also.

Comment: what is wrong with my terminology I'm only leaning this stuff so i'd like to know so i can improve on it :) ?

Comment: There is something called [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) and also I know about cyclically symmetric polynomials. But this is the first time I heard about something called cyclic polynomials.

Comment: oh right sorry that was a typo , I meant to write cylotomic polynomial